# Newer versions of Minikube don't allow Pods to use their own Services

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a Pod that occasionally needs to call itself by its own host-name.   I have a Deployment set up that ultimately creates the Pod, and a Service in place.  I'm able to use the service name from a different Pod within my cluster, but the Pod cannot call itself using its host-name.  This is something that works with Minikube v0.17.1 with Kubernetes version 1.5.3, but upgrading either Minikube or the Kubernetes version seems to break things.  This also works on our deployed / server version of Kubernetes.

Did something change that I need to take account of in my Pod / Service setup?  How do I go about getting past this?

### How things should work

Running Minikube version 0.17.1:

Start Minikube:

```
$ minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes cluster...
Starting VM...
SSH-ing files into VM...
Setting up certs...
Starting cluster components...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster.

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-01-12T04:57:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.3", GitCommit:"029c3a408176b55c30846f0faedf56aae5992e9b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"1970-01-01T00:00:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

$ minikube version
minikube version: v0.17.1
```

Deploy minimal test images (yaml definition below):

```
kubectl apply -f deploy_python.yaml
```

Exec into the python2 image, and verify connection to python image:

```
$ kubectl exec -it python2-1281934109-k015g bash
root@python2-1281934109-k015g:/# curl python:12345 --connect-timeout 10
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Directory listing for /</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Directory listing for /</h1>
<hr>
<ul>
<li><a href=".dockerenv">.dockerenv</a></li>
<li><a href="bin/">bin/</a></li>
<li><a href="boot/">boot/</a></li>
<li><a href="dev/">dev/</a></li>
<li><a href="etc/">etc/</a></li>
<li><a href="home/">home/</a></li>
<li><a href="lib/">lib/</a></li>
<li><a href="lib64/">lib64/</a></li>
<li><a href="media/">media/</a></li>
<li><a href="mnt/">mnt/</a></li>
<li><a href="opt/">opt/</a></li>
<li><a href="proc/">proc/</a></li>
<li><a href="root/">root/</a></li>
<li><a href="run/">run/</a></li>
<li><a href="sbin/">sbin/</a></li>
<li><a href="srv/">srv/</a></li>
<li><a href="sys/">sys/</a></li>
<li><a href="tmp/">tmp/</a></li>
<li><a href="usr/">usr/</a></li>
<li><a href="var/">var/</a></li>
</ul>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Exec into python image and verify connection to self:

```
$ kubectl exec -it python-2555691705-5j0f9 bash
root@python-2555691705-5j0f9:/# curl python:12345 --connect-timeout 10
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Directory listing for /</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Directory listing for /</h1>
<hr>
<ul>
<li><a href=".dockerenv">.dockerenv</a></li>
<li><a href="bin/">bin/</a></li>
<li><a href="boot/">boot/</a></li>
<li><a href="dev/">dev/</a></li>
<li><a href="etc/">etc/</a></li>
<li><a href="home/">home/</a></li>
<li><a href="lib/">lib/</a></li>
<li><a href="lib64/">lib64/</a></li>
<li><a href="media/">media/</a></li>
<li><a href="mnt/">mnt/</a></li>
<li><a href="opt/">opt/</a></li>
<li><a href="proc/">proc/</a></li>
<li><a href="root/">root/</a></li>
<li><a href="run/">run/</a></li>
<li><a href="sbin/">sbin/</a></li>
<li><a href="srv/">srv/</a></li>
<li><a href="sys/">sys/</a></li>
<li><a href="tmp/">tmp/</a></li>
<li><a href="usr/">usr/</a></li>
<li><a href="var/">var/</a></li>
</ul>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

That's a success.  By creating a Deployment and a Service, I'm able to make requests to the referenced Pod from any other Pod in the cluster.

### The way it works in newer versions

(Stop and delete running Minikube.)
Start Minikube, specifying Kubernetes version 1.7.0:

```
$ minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.7.0
Starting local Kubernetes cluster...
Starting VM...
SSH-ing files into VM...
Downloading localkube binary
137.48 MB / 137.48 MB [============================================] 100.00% 0s
Setting up certs...
Starting cluster components...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster.

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-01-12T04:57:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.0", GitCommit:"d3ada0119e776222f11ec7945e6d860061339aad", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-06-30T10:17:58Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Deploy minimal test images (yaml definition below):

```
$ kubectl apply -f deploy_python.yaml
service "python" created
deployment "python" created
deployment "python2" created
```

Exec into python 2 image, and verify connection to python image:

```
$ kubectl exec -it python2-380393367-ztgkq bash
root@python2-380393367-ztgkq:/# curl python:12345 --connect-timeout 10
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Directory listing for /</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Directory listing for /</h1>
<hr>
<ul>
<li><a href=".dockerenv">.dockerenv</a></li>
<li><a href="bin/">bin/</a></li>
<li><a href="boot/">boot/</a></li>
<li><a href="dev/">dev/</a></li>
<li><a href="etc/">etc/</a></li>
<li><a href="home/">home/</a></li>
<li><a href="lib/">lib/</a></li>
<li><a href="lib64/">lib64/</a></li>
<li><a href="media/">media/</a></li>
<li><a href="mnt/">mnt/</a></li>
<li><a href="opt/">opt/</a></li>
<li><a href="proc/">proc/</a></li>
<li><a href="root/">root/</a></li>
<li><a href="run/">run/</a></li>
<li><a href="sbin/">sbin/</a></li>
<li><a href="srv/">srv/</a></li>
<li><a href="sys/">sys/</a></li>
<li><a href="tmp/">tmp/</a></li>
<li><a href="usr/">usr/</a></li>
<li><a href="var/">var/</a></li>
</ul>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Exec into python image and attempt connection to self:

```
$ kubectl exec -it python-2168884431-gls2j bash
root@python-2168884431-gls2j:/# curl python:12345 --connect-timeout 10
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds
```

Yaml file, deploy_python.yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: python
spec:
  selector:
    app: python
  ports:
  - port: 12345
    targetPort: 12345
    name: http
---    
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: python
  labels:
    app: python
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: python
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: python
        name: python
        command: ["python"]
        args: ["-m", "http.server", "12345" ]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 12345
---    
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: python2
  labels:
    app: python2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: python2
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: python
        name: python2
        command: ["python"]
        args: ["-m", "http.server", "12345" ]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 12345
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in newer versions of kubernetes / minikube and is being tracked here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20475

The current accepted workaround (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20475#issuecomment-190995739) is to ssh into your minikube vm and run a specific ip link command.

```
minikube ssh
sudo ip link set docker0 promisc on
```

I have tested this workaround and it seems to work for me.